# How to add variable number buttons in uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS development. In my app i'm using tableview for displaying data. When getting data from server each data for the day needs to be shown in a single cell. Each data needs be shown on button which can be clicked to download the data.
Example.
For today there are 3 data objects, So 3 buttons need be created inside a single cell.
For yesterday there are 5 data objects, so 5 buttons are needed to be inside the single cell.
Also the row height should vary accordingly.
How to achieve it?

And also how to use the added buttons effectively.

Thank you

Comment: Show your code, what did you try?

Comment: Should buttons be positioned vertically one above another and be equal to table view width or how?

Comment: the buttons should be placed one above the other vertically

Answer (score 1):

For set row height according to it's content you should set tableview's two properties

```
_tableViewOne.estimatedRowHeight = 50; //minimum row height
_tableViewOne.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

so it will take row height according to it's content.

> Don't use tableview's heightForRowAtIndexPath method otherwise above code will not work (it will override those properties).

and for dynamically add buttons you can create them and add subview them in cell at runtime in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method.

If u want every button's user interaction then u can set every button's tag property according to indexpath.row and than call same mathod when any those button get clicked and then u can uniquely identify those buttons from there tag.

Example code:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 1:
            //do something
            break;
        case 2:
            //do something
            break;
        case 3:
            //do something
            break;
        case 4:
            //do something
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

}

Comment: I tried this. i already have a label in the cell with variable height. I need to add the button below the label. the row height is not changing.

Comment: Have u used tableview's heightForRowAtIndexPath method in ur code.??

Comment: used both height for indexpath and estimated row height. also i need to give user interaction to buttons and did select row at index path

Comment: Don't use tableview's **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method otherwise above code will not work (it will override those properties).